# Where does virt-manager store config files?

Tags: virt-manager

I checked `~/.libvirt*` and `~/.config/libvirt*`, non of them seem to contain config file of created VM, where is the config stored? I'm not running virt-manager as root user.

Comment: Just FYI, Debian/sid(9), virt-manager version 1:1.0.1-5 change the config to "~/.config/dconf/user"

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Oddly enough, under `/etc/libvirt`. virt-manager doesn't run as root, but it communicates with libvirtd that *does*.

Comment: correct, and now 2019 Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 still use it in `ls -lah /etc/libvirt/qemu/`

Comment: For anyone who came here searching for where it stores the operating system images, it's in `/var/lib/libvirt/images/`. You can find out the location in the options to clone the virtual machine. When you select `Clone this disk` and select `Details`.

Comment: That's libvirt's config, not the virt-manager's itself as the question was asking.  Virt-manager is just a client app that communicates with libvirt.

Answer (score 15):

Client information (eg connection strings) is stored in the `dconf` (accessible with `dconf-editor`) under `/org/virt-manager/virt-manager/`.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for

Comment: me too, though it's not an answer to this question

Comment: @reedstrm for that you should look where dconf stores its files: https://developer.gnome.org/dconf/unstable/dconf-overview.html

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to know too. dbus wasn't running and hence configs were not being saved.

Comment: Me too on Ubuntu 18. After `apt install dconf-editor` connections are now saved.

Comment: Now they are gone again...

Answer (score 4):

virt-manager config is on

```
~/.gconf/apps/virt-manager/
```

Comment: this is where I found my stored connection settings for virt-manager

Comment: This is probably the old config path.